# I am doing a Xamarin cross platform project and can't display uri images on my UI. I always get this an error saying the bitmap is too large

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am doing a Xamarin project for school and can't display any uri images on my user interface. I always get this error in the debug window:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(241238816bytes) bitmap.

This is cross platform so I can't just set a height and width request and Xamarin does the work for me. I can't just download picasso or FFImageLoading from Nuget and pass a few parameters because this is Android AND iOS. No UWP by the way. Just Android and iOS. I saw something on Github for resizing images but that's for image files, not uri's. Saving the uri image as a file first doesn't work because most of them are 200+ MB each! I need to pass the "Image" source to the ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(myUriIWantToPass));
I understand I am probably going to have to write code to pass the uri string, height request, width request. Make a new Bitmap that's scaled down. Then load it and then set the Image source to the new scaled down bitmap somehow. I will copy and paste code for the backend of the page. It's called PlantProfilePage.xaml.cs and that code should be enough to go by for an answer.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            FamilyName.BindingContext = this;
            GenusName.BindingContext = this;
            ScientificName.BindingContext = this;
            //PlantPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(uriList[0].ToString()));
            string url = "https://collections.nmnh.si.edu/media/index.php?irn=11986034";
            //string encodedURL = Uri.EscapeDataString(url);
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.BeginGetResponse((IAsyncResult arg) =>
                {
                    Stream stream = request.EndGetResponse(arg).GetResponseStream();
                    ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => PlantPicture.Source = imageSource);
                }, null);

                //PlantPicture.Source = UriImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(url));
            }
            catch (UriFormatException ufe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Uri didn't work: " + ufe);
            }
```

I need to resize these uri string's I'm using from hundreds of megabytes to something that won't cause the project to give me the error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(241238816bytes) bitmap.

This should work for both Android and iOS both.

Comment: FFImageLoading works with XF - https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API

Comment: alternatively, I'd suggest using something like https://images.weserv.nl/

Comment: The url I hardcoded in the code section is just one I'm trying to display. Once I get that to show on the UI, I'm going to comment it out and go back to displaying any uri image from a database I'm querying for uri images.

Comment: I never assumed you were using just one hardcoded url.  That doesn't change my suggestions

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to start trying suggestions now. I'll post back later.

Comment: FFImageLoading can downsample and cache those bitmap (of course this is local processing and storage which may or not be an issue). Personally I would resize those on the server side to reduce the size, transmission time, data consumption and local processing/storage. i.e. In your case via a proxy server that you control to perform the image processing.

Comment: @SushiHangover that's exactly what the service I suggested above will do for him

Comment: So I added FFImageLoading and am getting this error:

Comment: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load list of method overrides due to Method not found: void Xamarin. I have Xamarin.Forms v3.6.0.264807 and have FFImageLoading.Forms v2.4.4.859....I've also tried all the different ways to write the code in Mainactivity.cs file such as 1.) CachedImageRenderer.Init() 2.) CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true) 3.) CachedImageRenderer.Init(true)....

Comment: The FFImageloading worked for both Android and iOS. I got it to work. I didn't know you could use it for both platforms. I read some bad information on another webpage so I was left with the wrong impression.

Answer (score 2):

The FFImageLoading worked. It will show scaled down uri images for the Android and iPhone screen.